# Asynchronous API handling with PHP

Tags: php, api, asynchronous, promise

I have this PHP function that logs the visitors to a `.txt` file (for security reasons). It uses an API to get their location. It works fine on `localhost`, but when it's actually live it logs empty values. I'm assuming it's because the functions runs before the API has had time to return the data. Is there a way to write something like a Javascript `promise` or some asynchronous function that will wait for the data to return before logging it?

This is what I currently have:

```
function getLocation() {
    $query = @unserialize (file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'));
    if ($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
        $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("H:i:s d-m-Y").' - '.$query['country'].', '.$query['regionName'].', '.$query['city'].', '.$query['zip'];
        $file = '../logs/userlog.txt';
        $currentFileData = file_get_contents($file);
        $currentFileData .= $user . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($file, $currentFileData);
    }
}
```

What the output **should** be:

```
127.0.0.1 - 11:59:33 03-04-2020 - South Africa, Western Cape, Cape Town, 8001
```

What the **actual** output is:

```
127.0.0.1 - 11:59:33 03-04-2020 - , , ,
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the IP address as stated in the [documentation](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php) after the /php/ part of the URL. It should be

```
$query = @unserialize (file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

Comment: What you are suggesting here is right, thanks so much! But I actually found that the `php` version of this API has been deprecated—I wouldn't have gotten to that issue if it wasn't for your post, so I'm going to upvote it as helpful and then just post the fix. Thanks again @DanielProtopopov !

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** Thanks to @DanielProtopopov's post I actually found on the documentation that this `php` version of the API has been deprecated. So using @DanielProtopopov's fix I have to use the JSON API for it to work:

```
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

Comment: You should select Daniel's answer as the correct one - both to give him the credit/points and to show that the issue has been solved